# opening excel file in the same directory

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a new workbook which is there in the same directory as my current workbook. I saw this command to open it, but it is showing me an error. The error says that it cannot find the file in another directory.

```
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\source.xlsx")
```

The above command does not open the file source.xlsx and in the error, it is trying to look in the folder c:\user\username\AppData ....

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ActiveWorkbook.Path`

Comment: Is the extention of the other file xlsx ? cause its working at my end

Comment: OP says both workbooks in same directory so why advise against using `ThisWorkbook.Path` ?

Comment: Thanks Gadziu. It worked. If have a folder in the current directory named test, can I use the following to get into an excel file using Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test\source.xlsx")

Comment: I don't really understand what you say. Can you form question one more?

Comment: lets us say in the current directory i have a folder named test. Inside this test folder let us assume that I have an excel file named myfile.xlsx. Can I use Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test\myfile.xlsx") to open the myfile.xlsx from the present vba script?

Answer (score 2):

ThisWorkbook.Path is referring to this path c:\user\username\AppData ....

Try using `ActiveWorkbook.Path` instead of `ThisWorkbook.Path`